# Unity Android UdpClient.Send Access Denied

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, udp

I am attempting to get my Unity Android game talking over the local WiFi. When everything is running from a desktop computer all of my code works flawlessly. However, when I deploy the game to Android I keep getting an Access Denied exception when I call the below code.

```
UdpClientClient = new UdpClient();
....
Client.Send(requestData, requestData.Length, "192.168.1.255", 3310); //Access Denied
```

I have the below permission in my Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you share the entire error message and on what phone,  which android version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to enable broadcast before sending the data.